# SQL Server Management Studio weird Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I get some weird error message when i start SQL server Management studio. I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 in my local box.

I get new Error Message every time I try open SSMS.

"glass-desked_gsk"
"mlass-desked_gsk"

The above error message will shown in a message box with some Chinese Characters.

Comment: Kill it. Kill it with fire. Joking aside, is this a fresh install?  Was it working before and it just started happening?

Comment: It was work earlier. all of a sudden i am facing this issue.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the error? Smells like virus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to Reinstall sql server 2008 R2 and sharepoint. This took care of the issues.